# Difference between "⌘ + ↓" vs. "Double Click" vs. Right Click → Open when launching an .app?

Tags: macos, finder, mojave

I noticed that if I perform <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> on foo.app, it will display a different output vs. right clicking and selecting Open vs. double clicking.

This is a Wineskin application. <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>↓</kbd> launches Wineskin, not what I want. Right Click → Open actually launches the program Wineskin is wrapping, which is what I want.

Why is the behaviour of all these methods different?